# ImportError at /hello/ Module "myapp.templates" does not define a "hello" attribute/class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web-applications, django-templates

I'm trying to make a simple webapp using Django 2.0.2. But I'm getting ImportError. Searched a lot but didn't find a way to resolve it. Can someone please help me with this error. Module "myapp.templates" does not define a "hello" attribute/class.

Here's my code

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def hello(request):
   return render(request,'hello.html',{})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import hello as myapp_hello
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', myapp_hello),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'x+ve9z=f1_%t@*4uo@!h#b*!g-1ayc1d4+ct$q853nczss)#5c'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjProject.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myapp.templates.hello',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjProject.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Folder Structure**

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── DjProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── myapp
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   ├── hello.html
    │   └── __pycache__
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py

8 directories, 23 files
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
ImportError at /hello/

Module "myapp.templates" does not define a "hello" attribute/class

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/
Django Version:     2.0.2
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

Module "myapp.templates" does not define a "hello" attribute/class

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py in import_string, line 24
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.3
Python Path:    

['/home/sukumar/PycharmProjects/DjProject',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 4 Feb 2018 19:58:43 +0000
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `'myapp.templates.hello'` to `'myapp.hello'` ?

Comment: What's the point of this `'myapp.templates.hello'` in template options? There aren't any modules in `myapp.templates`. You cannot import `hello` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: There is myapp.views.hello, but that's not a context processor so shouldn't be in that list anyway.